# Need help with CSS3 3D transforms

Tags: animation, css, 3d

Please have a look at this page:

http://www.abhi.my/lab/3D-menu.html

If you haven't already guessed, I'm trying to emulate the new iOS notification animation (that's where I first saw it), and obviously, my two paltry div's aren't behaving like a full box...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here...?

This is what I'd like to get close to: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBgVbzBJqDc

Comment: Lol... C'mon guys... 12 Views and no answers? I greatly appreciate the Likes and all, but no suggestions on how I can make it better?

Comment: @BoldClock - Hey mate, mind letting me know what edit you've made to my post?

Comment: everyone here is helping for free. You need to be patient. And to see what edits have been made, you can click on the time next to "edited", to see the revision history (in this case, it was a retagging)

Comment: @Damien - Lol, don't get me wrong mate, I wasn't trying to come across as pushy... But every other single question I've asked has been answered in less than 2 hours... Apologies to the world if I came across as a complete jackass... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only transforming you elements in 2d space, even though you are going for a 3d effect.

A working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/mrlundis/wU296/

The "bottom" span is positioned behind the "front" span by using `translate3d(x,y,z)` where `y` and `z` correspond to half of the elements height (it's rotated around it center point.) It should be possible to achieve the same effect using `-webkit-transform-origin`.

`-webkit-transform-origin` is also used to make sure the containing div rotates around it's center point on hover.

Comment: Ok, your example is great, that's everything I was looking for... But could you please explain it a bit more... The 'bottom' span is translated to appear as the bottom face of the supposed cube. So you're basically baking in the position of the 'faces', and then transforming the container element (the one with the perspective set?) Also, not to complain, but with these kind of transforms applied, I have noticed that there's the occasional chance that the transform does not trigger when the element is hovered... Is this a technological limitation, or are we missing something in implementation?

Comment: Oh, and what's the 15px for in the -webkit-transform-origin? I thought the only accepted values were x & y?

Comment: Ok, done... I got more or less what I was aiming for... I understood the situation a tad bit better thanks your help mr_lundis, and you have been credited accordingly in the Demo... You may navigate to the link provided in the OP to view... :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's right – I position the spans the way I like them and then rotate the container. `-webkit-transform-origin` does take a third argument that sets the origin for z. See the [Surfing Safari blog](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/).

I also noticed that the transform didn't always trigger – dont know why. You could try increasing the size if the div to compensate (i.e. add som padding.)

Comment: The tempermental triggering of the transform animation was fixed by creating and placing a transparent div below the nav element to block any hover interaction... Apparently the bottom portion of the nav was causing the awkwardness, but has been remedied to the best of my abilities... Do check the demo again to see it in effect... P.S. Do you have an alternative source that I can credit? Linking back to your SO profile is a little dry... :-p

Comment: Linking back here is fine. Another little hint: move the box-shadow to a containing element or replace it with some gradients for a more realistic shadow and to prevent it moving with the boxes, which look rather awkward.

Comment: Lol, yeah, I was looking into that... Just got side tracked with some flash light effects via css3 gradients... :-p